# Receber e converter stream de server remoto para string

Tags: ruby

Estou fazendo um script que recebe um stream, em formato hexadecimal,de um servidor remoto via conexão TCP, afim de quebrar a sua criptografia e ler uma mensagem ASCII que se encontra nele. Meu objetivo e ler esse stream, e converte-lo para string, a fim de rodar o script que fiz (que considera como input somente strings).

Eu sou novo em Ruby. Não estou conseguindo nem ao menos ler o stream que chega ao meu programa. Eu posso, através de um site provido para esse desafio, visualizar os packets que saem do servidor. Eles são assim:

```
003B60558EB661BC55D2305E4A8AC07E6D518ABEE7A2BFE7B7B2A5E7B6B2AEBDE7A4B5A8B0A3E7A0A6B1A2E7ADA8BEA1B2ABE7B3AFA6A9ACB4E901
```

E tenho recebido isso no meu terminal (em tentativas pífias de ao menos ler o stream):

```
7�����焉(��hX@FB^T\[NSVQC]BZG^YPMRUEVDARO
```

Como ler esse stream, converte-lo para o seu formato normal normal e , finalmente, o converter para string?

Answer (score 0):

Para converter o stream para string você pode utilizar o seguinte one-liner:

```
"<seu stream hex>".split('').each_slice(2).map {|char| char.join.hex.chr }.join
```

é não é uma solução elegante, mas é suficiente pra suprir sua necessidade.

Quanto a parte de conexão com o socket TCP e leitura dos pacotes vindos do servidor, dê uma olhada na classe TCPSocket da biblioteca-padrão do Ruby (a última versão, 2.2.1, pode ser encontrada aqui: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html).